# Parsing code with caseless keyword with Tatsu / grako

Tags: python, parsing, keyword, tatsu

I try to parse Fortran code with keyword which are caseless with Tatsu h!
Is there a smarter way to define the keyword caseless than these :

```
@@ keyword :: integer INTEGER etc...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `@@ignorecase` directive, as explained [here](http://tatsu.readthedocs.io/en/stable/syntax.html#case-sensitivity)